# Recommended Jedis version for Java 1.6

Tags: java, redis, compatibility, jedis

Appreciate if somebody could provide expert opinion on what is the most recommended Jedis version for Java 1.6. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Git history, Jedis updated to Java 1.7 on 04.07.2016 https://github.com/redis/jedis/pull/1334

The latest release before this date would be version 2.8.1 from 14.03.2016 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis/2.8.1

Assuming there would be no changes of the required JDK within a patch version you could also use version 2.8.2 from 22.07.2016 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis/2.8.2

But to be honest, try everything to update your JDK 6 to to current LTS JDK 17. It will be much easier to update ANY dependency you have to fix security vulnerabilities, which I am almost sure you have, when you are bound to JDK 6 dependencies, which tend to not receive any updates since a looong time.

Comment: Thanks for your response on this. It's really helpful. Any idea on what is the latest Redis version supported by that Jedis version. Will it support most recent Redis version as well?

Comment: @ShehanCharuka Please ask your question in comment in a new 'Ask Question' post.

Comment: No idea. You can try to use the same approach, checking which Redis version was the newest at the time of publishing and try to find the set of available APIs at that version and see if the APIs have changed.

Comment: @Simulant Thank you very much for your ideas, Appreciate the corporation.